# Hide active div on next element mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide the tooltips div which I will show on the div click so once mouse over on next div the previous div tooltips hide. But its hiding when mouse leave on the next div area.

https://codepen.io/codepat007/pen/BazYXKo

My Code

```js
$(".tooltipsShow").click(function() {
  $(".tooltips").show();
});


$(".tooltipsShow").hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll().eq(0).find(".tooltipsText").parent(".tooltips").hide();
});
```

```css
.tooltips {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  position:absolute; 
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  background: green;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltipsShow">
  <p>Some text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="tooltipsShow">
  <p>Some text 2</p>
</div>
<div class="tooltipsShow">
  <p>Some text 3</p>
</div>
<div class="tooltipsShow">
  <p>Some text 4</p>
</div>

<div class="tooltips"><p class="tooltipsText">I am tooltips</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just hide the tooltip div on hover

```
$(".tooltipsShow").hover(function() {
   console.log('hover');
  $(".tooltips").hide();
});
```